# Remote debugging failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging, attach-to-process

While trying to perform remote debugging, I fell into the following error message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named '10.10.10.10:4022'.  
The Remote Debugger was unable to locate a resource dll (vsdebugeng.impl.resources.dll).  
Please ensure that the complete remote debugger folder was copied or installed on the target computer.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

- I have already tried restarting `msvsmon.exe` on the remote machine, both in the "x86" and the "x64" directory.
- I've already tried launching `msvsmon.exe` normally and as administrator.
- I can confirm that `msvsmon.exe` is running: it says something like "Msvsmon started a new server named "...:4022". Waiting for new connections.
- When trying to make a connection, I see following error message in the remote debugger: "Failed attempt to connect from `<Domain>\<username>`. I can confirm that this login information is correct.
- The mentioned file (`vsdebugend.....dll`) does exist on the remote computer.

Does anybody know what I might still try?
Thanks

Comment: Did you publish and deploy the application using the setup.exe file like any commercial software?  Are you running the code from debug or release folder? Can you run the release executable on the build machine?

Comment: Windows firewall?

Comment: There's an installer for the remote debugger. Did you use that one?

Comment: As far as I know, the customer is using an official remote debugger.